# How to re-throw a Throwable?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

Consider this code:

```java
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testSaveEmptyApplication() {
    try {
        Application application = new Application();
        Application result = applicationService.save(application);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(e instanceof UncheckedServiceException) {
            throw e.getCause(); // java.lang.Throwable, compiler error
        }
    }
}
```

How to re-throw a Throwable?

Comment: did you try `testSaveEmptyApplication() throws Throwable`?

Comment: Please paste the error message from the compiler into your question so we can all be sure what we are talking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is it legal to re-throw a Throwable in certain cases, without declaring it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581611/why-is-it-legal-to-re-throw-a-throwable-in-certain-cases-without-declaring-it)

Comment: Maybe related: [Re-throw an InvocationTargetException target exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214525/re-throw-an-invocationtargetexception-target-exception). Search for more.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `testSaveEmptyApplication` is not declared to throw any checked exceptions.  But `e.getCause()` returns `Throwable` which is a checked exception.  So what you are doing in your example code is breaking Java's checked exception rules.

If you **know** that the cause really is a `RuntimeException`, then you can do this

```
throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();
```

Caveats:

- However, if your assumption is incorrect and the cause exception's actual class is a checked exception, the above will result in a (brand new) `ClassCastException` which squashes the cause exception you were trying to rethrow.
- The above will also break if the cause was an `Error`, but you could deal with that; e.g something like this.

  ```
   Throwable cause = e.getCause();
   if (cause instanceof RuntimeException) {
       throw (RuntimeException) cause;
   } else if (cause instanceof Error) {
       throw (Error) cause;
   } else {
       throw new AssertionError("Unexpected exception class", cause);
   }
  ```
- If you want to be able to rethrow checked exceptions, then they must be declared in the method signature.  Once you have done that you can discriminate and throw them as per the above pattern.

This is all a bit cumbersome.  But this is the price you pay for having wrapped the exception in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can think of for there is:

The catch clause to be:

```java
try {
  // ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof UncheckedServiceException) {
        if(e.getCause() instanceof NullPointerException) {
            throw new NullPointerException(e.getCause().getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Otherwise change the method signature like this:

```java
public void method() throws Throwable {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: This is throwing a new exception ... with a different stacktrace to the original "cause" exception.